# How to download and upload a file while executing the tests on device farm(Desktop browser)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I am executing my selenium tests in aws device farm desktop browser. I have to perform below steps.

- Download a file
- Update the file content
- Upload the same file

In local these steps works perfectly fine. How to achieve the same while running the tests in device farm.